# Rails ActiveRecord : search in multiple values with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

So let's say I have Post, Category and Categorizations models.

A post can have many categories through categorizations.

Now, how can I pull out all the posts that match at least one item of an array of categories?

Example:

```
Post 1 has categories 2,5,6
Post 2 has categories 1,5,9
Post 3 has categories 2,4,8
Find posts that match 3,5
```

I want the posts 1 and 2 to be returned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Categorization` is a join model for `Post` and `Category`:

```
Post.joins(:categorizations).where(:categorizations => {:category_id => [3, 5]})
```

If it's not, and `Categorization` actually `has_many :categories` then:

```
Post.joins(:categories).where(:categories=> {:id => [3, 5]})
```

Note that the second method will work in the first case as well, however it will require 2 SQL joins and thus may not perform as well.